# git tagのpushを制限する方法

Tags: git, github, gitlab

GitLabでデフォルトブランチへの"v"で始まるタグ付けでリリースを行うように設定しています。
v1.0.0というようなタグをmainブランチにpushすることでビルド／テスト／デプロイを実行します。

developer権限のユーザは、作業ブランチやマージリクエストを作成できます。
作業ブランチに対してコミットやタグをpushすることもできます。

下記の２つのケースを禁止するような良い方法がありますでしょうか。

- developer権限のユーザがv1.0.0のタグをpushする
- デフォルトブランチ以外にv1.0.0のタグを誤ってpushする

タグはブランチに関係なく一意な名前となるので、作業ブランチであっても勝手に使われてしまうと困ります。

Answer (score 4):

GitLab ではMaintainerが管理画面で設定できます(EE/CE共通機能)。

- [Protected tags | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_tags.html)

GitHub ではAPI経由ですが、現在パブリックベータ機能として利用できるようです。

- [Private beta: Protected tags · Discussion #10906 · github/feedback · GitHub](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/10906)

  > Hi folks! Just a note to say we've now moved this to public beta so the feature should be available for all public repositories on GitHub and in private repositories on paid plans.

どちらも glob で保護するタグ名パターンを設定する方式です。

Comment: Protected Tagに下記を設定してvで始まるタグをメンテナーだけがpushできるようになりました。Tagに"v*"、Allowed to createにMaintainersを設定

Comment: Protected Tagでは、メンテナーが誤ってデフォルトブランチ以外にタグ付けは禁止できないので、メンテナーが注意するしかないようです。